# Прочитал "Изучаем Python (Марк Лутц)" что читать дальше?

Tags: python

Прочитал 2 тома очень  понравилось, но что читать дальше не знаю.

Comment: Хватит читать. Решайте задачки на специальных сайтах. Делайте какие-то реальные проекты. Хотя бы освойте `Google Colab` и экспериментируйте там по-всякому.

Comment: Пишите код. Решайте реальные проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

А цель-то у вас какая?  Просто учить язык? Или все-таки учиться программировать на нем? Если первая - то берете любую книгу по Python (благо на сегодня их уже несколько десятков на русском языке)и читаете, зубрите. Потом - вторую, третью.... ну в общем и себя удовлетворили чтением, и цель "учить язык" достигнута.

А вот если хотите учиться программировать - то тогда берете какой-нибудь проект (выбираете себе по вкусу, что-бы интересно было) и пытаетесь его реализовать. Знаний для старта у вас должно хватить для любого вразумительного проекта. Правда, это при условии, что вы УЧИЛИ язык по Лутцу, а не ПРОЧИТАЛИ, но тут уж мы ничего не можем сказать. Когда при выполнении этого проекта натыкаетесь на что-то, чего не знаете - лезете в книги и ищете в них (или в интернет) конкретный ответ. Ну, или в крайнем случае (!!) задаете вопросы на форуме.  И так шаг за шагом - к поставленной цели "стать программистом".

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую поизучать о Python на metanit.com, там научился писать на питоне, все просто и понятно